# Sony F312 и база данных

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть телефон Sony F3112 версия ОС Android 6.0. Проблема заключается вот в чём.

При первой установке моего приложения, которое использует базу данных на данной модели прошло успешно и работало без проблем, но при повторной установке (когда я добавил в поля новые таблицы) предварительно удалил приложение, при записи в базу в консоли ругается и приложение падает.

У меня такое подозрение, что при удалении приложения не удалилась старая база, а новую базу в которой есть новые поля, на которые ругается отладчик он не видит или она просто упорно не устонавливаеться. При этом я и удалял приложение, чистил кэш, на всякий случай удалял папку из телефона с бд, но ничего не помогло. И самое главное на остальных телефонах разной версии, всё прекрасно работает.

Вот пример:

```
08-31 18:19:27.829 3233-3233/com.example.vadim.dpapp E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 6 rows, 5 columns.
08-31 18:19:27.840 3233-3233/com.example.vadim.dpapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Task has no column named Waypoint
08-31 18:19:27.842 3233-3233/com.example.vadim.dpapp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Kontracter=ЖБК Waypoint=Проверка автором Complite=Нет isApproved=Нет Ispolnitel=Наумчик Алексей Date=26.07.2017 16:11:20 Code=2532 nextExecutor= Name=На проверку: Тестовая задача
                                                                       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Task has no column named Waypoint (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Task(Kontracter,Waypoint,Complite,isApproved,Ispolnitel,Date,Code,nextExecutor,Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:896)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:507)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1493)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1365)
                                                                           at com.example.vadim.dpapp.application.DBHelper.addTask(DBHelper.java:87)
                                                                           at com.example.vadim.dpapp.application.RESTController$1.onResponse(RESTController.java:158)
                                                                           at com.example.vadim.dpapp.application.RESTController$1.onResponse(RESTController.java:80)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> table Task has no column named Waypoint

Означает, что таблица `Task` не содержит столбца `Waypoint`, так что да - Ваше предположение верно.
Проверьте базу данных на предмет наличия всех полей, либо ее версию, перед операцией добавления нового элемента в нее. Быть может, база без необходимого столбца, либо в случае программного создания базы - ошибочная реализация.

Comment: точно такая же apk устанавливалась на других смартфонах без проблем

Comment: Опять же - проверьте код. Версия Android такая же на других устройствах, место создания базы по умолчанию?

Comment: проблему решил простым переименованием базы, видимо на телефоне она пересоздалась, и всё заработало